# How to know when a ref has its referenced html element?

Tags: reactjs

I have an html elemenent which is a virtual keyboard that appears and disappears. Then inside a useefect I am trying to set the element"s hight and width inside a  size state. But when I console.log inside myref.current.getboundingrect().height or width, I get undefined always.
As a ref does not trigger the useefect, how could I check when the ref has its size attributes? Even before that, how can I check that the ref.current has the html element?

My useefect has isVisiblekeyboard state as a dependency but seems like when triggered the useefect, the element is not in the reference yet.

Comment: Can you paste your code and make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?